# Tengo problemas al generar un pdf de aproximadamente 1000 registros

Tags: php, laravel

Este es el error que me tira al momento de generar mi `pfd` como que excedo el limite permitido de `bytes` pero no se como solucionarlo.

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Alguna sugerencia**

**Este es mi controlador** en el cual realizo la petición para mostrar los artículos:

```
 public function listarPdf(){
        $articulos = Articulo::join('categorias','articulos.idcategoria','=','categorias.id')
            ->select('articulos.id','articulos.idcategoria','articulos.codigo','articulos.nombre',
            'categorias.nombre as nombre_categoria','articulos.precio_venta','articulos.stock',
            'articulos.descripcion','articulos.condicion')
            ->orderBy('articulos.nombre', 'asc')->get();

        $cont=Articulo::count();

        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.articulospdf',['articulos'=>$articulos,'cont'=>$cont])->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
        return $pdf->download('articulos.pdf');
    }
```

Este es mi código del `pdf` al momento de realizar mi petición pero me esta tirando este error. Al principio si me funcionaba correctamente pero a medida fui ingresando datos, este me empezó a fallar y no se cual puede ser el problema.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Reporte de Artículos</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.875rem;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 1.5;
            color: #151b1e;           
        }
        .table {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
            background-color: transparent;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .table-bordered {
            border: 1px solid #c2cfd6;
        }
        thead {
            display: table-header-group;
            vertical-align: middle;
            border-color: inherit;
        }
        tr {
            display: table-row;
            vertical-align: inherit;
            border-color: inherit;
        }
        .table th, .table td {
            padding: 0.75rem;
            vertical-align: top;
            border-top: 1px solid #c2cfd6;
        }
        .table thead th {
            vertical-align: bottom;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #c2cfd6;
        }
        .table-bordered thead th, .table-bordered thead td {
            border-bottom-width: 2px;
        }
        .table-bordered th, .table-bordered td {
            border: 1px solid #c2cfd6;
        }
        th, td {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: inherit;
        }
        th {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: -internal-center;
            text-align: left;
        }
        tbody {
            display: table-row-group;
            vertical-align: middle;
            border-color: inherit;
        }
        tr {
            display: table-row;
            vertical-align: inherit;
            border-color: inherit;
        }
        .table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        }
        .izquierda{
            float:left;
        }
        .derecha{
            float:right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Lista de Artículos <span class="derecha">{{now()}}</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Categoría</th>
                    <th>Precio Venta</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($articulos as $a)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$a->codigo}}</td>
                    <td>{{$a->nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{$a->nombre_categoria}}</td>
                    <td>{{$a->precio_venta}}</td>
                    <td>{{$a->stock}}</td>
                    <td>{{$a->descripcion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$a->condicion?'Activo':'Desactivado'}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach                                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="izquierda">
        <p><strong>Total de registros: </strong>{{$cont}}</p>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

lo modifique de esta forma

```
public function listarPdf(){ 
        ini_set('memory_limit', 'XX');
        $articulos = Articulo::join('categorias','articulos.idcategoria','=','categorias.id')
            ->select('articulos.id','articulos.idcategoria','articulos.codigo','articulos.nombre',
            'categorias.nombre as nombre_categoria','articulos.precio_venta','articulos.stock',
            'articulos.descripcion','articulos.condicion')
            ->orderBy('articulos.nombre', 'asc')->get();

        $cont=Articulo::count();

        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.articulospdf',['articulos'=>$articulos,'cont'=>$cont])->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
        return $pdf->download('articulos.pdf');
    }
```

Comment: en realidad el error es PHP no postgres, estas superando el maximo de memoria de una variable

Comment: como puedo solucionar este problema entonces estoy viendo que si me lo genero una vez ahorita pero de ahi no me lo volvio a generar

Comment: actualiza en tu PHP esta linea `ini_set('memory_limit', 'XX');` donde XX es el limite del valor que le quieras colocar

Comment: yo estoy utilizando laravel en que parte encuentro ini_set('memory_limit', 'XX'); soy nuevo en esto

Comment: lo agregas al archivo PHP que hace la carga/descarga

Comment: el archivo que hace la carga o descarga pero no es en la vista del pdf o en el controlador no se muy bien disculpe no saber estuve viendo pero con laravel no encuentro

Comment: en el controlador

Comment: el controlador es el que tengo arriba pero ahi solo realizo la consulta para que me genere el pdf y no se si ahi agrego o como hacer

Comment: `public function listarPdf(){ ini_set('memory_limit', 'XX'); ......` porque no pruebas ahí?

Answer (score 0):

El procesador php por lo general limita el tamaño de la memoria que se puede consumir en cada *request* que atiende. En este caso, 134,217,728 son 128MB de memoria, que ya es una suma bastante considerable.

Si de todas formas quieres permitir que un solo *request* consuma mas memoria, puedes cambiar el archivo `php.ini` para establecer el parámetro `memory_limit` a un valor mayor. Toma en cuenta que un valor de `-1` significa: Memoria ilimitada.

Incluso, puedes cambiarlo *dinámicamente*, por ejemplo, antes de generar este archivo *pdf*, con una instrucción similar a:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Con esto, el proceso podrá tomar de manera ilimitada la memoria.

Si utilizas un *hosting* compartido, debes tomar en cuenta que es probable que en la mayoría el administrador del *host* no permitirá que se ajuste dinámicamente este parámetro, pues conlleva el riesgo de que el servidor pueda caer en caso de sobrecarga.

Comment: entiendo perfectamente lo realize en una computadora actualmente estoy trabajando con xampp pero lo hice en una y me funciono correctamente el detalle esta cuando la ingreso a otra computadora me dice que exedi el maximo a 30 segundos y no me hace la peticion

Comment: Excelente, me alegra que se haya resuelto tu problema. En StackOverflow, para un nuevo problema, una nueva pregunta. Por favor lee  [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Un saludo.